# log4net: Specify log level dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

Instead of `log.Debug(...)` or `log.Info(...)` I want to write code like this:

```
var logLevel = GetLogLevel(); // Returns something like DEBUG or INFO
log.Log(logLevel, ...);
```

How to do that in log4net in an *easy and convinient* way?

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's a duplicate.

Comment: You might be misunderstanding what Log Levels ate, you use it to tell what kind of message this is, and on the other end you describe what level of detail you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend ILog with extensions methods:

```
public static Level GetLogLevel(this ILog log)
{
     if (log.IsEnabledFor(Level.Debug)) { return Level.Debug; }
     else ....
}

public static void Log(this ILog log, Level level, ...)
{
    switch(level) ....
}
```

However normally you would adjust the logger to get messages from a specific log level and not change the level that is being logged in code. If you are changing the level, you can better log all messages on fatal level.